# Bootstrap 5.3 Scrollable Modal with Form in body and submit button in footer

Tags: forms, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a scrollable modal dialog with a form in the **modal-body**. It is a long form, vertically, so I would like to utilize the **modal-footer** section to house the submit button since it stays stationary when scrolling the form/body.

I am using a straight forward modal structure like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body">
        ... FORM CONTENT ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem comes in when I try to insert the `<form>` and `</form>` tags. If I put `<form>` before **modal-body** and I put `</form>` after **modal-footer**, it breaks the static nature of the footer as well as the scrollable nature of the body.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <form action=".....">
        <div class="modal-body">
          ... FORM CONTENT ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I understand that I could keep the form itself contained within **modal-body** and use a standard button outside of the form in order to submit the form via javascript, but I would prefer to keep the button inside the form so the form submits when `enter` is pressed.

I've also tried moving the form tags around the `.modal` div, around the `.modal-dialog` div and around the `.modal-content` div and each time it breaks the modal in a different way.

I have reconstructed this issue here: https://codepen.io/JayblesG/pen/MWRjvOx

Has anyone had success in accomplishing something like this?

Comment: Maybe not the best semantically but, it seems to work if you use the `form` as the `.modal-body`, just drop the inner `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine if you use modal-content as the `<form>`...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <form class="modal-content" action="/echo" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-header bg-secondary fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
                    <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
                    <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
                    <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
                    <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer bg-secondary">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/qFI1p5Dh27

This way you can use the HTML form submit button.

Comment: Brilliant and simple. No idea how I didn't come up with that. Cheers!